# Proposition 0.2 Introduction to PDE's - Folland, G.

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

I'm reading the following proposition of Introducion to PDE's of G. Folland but I don't understand the following part:

> For each $x\in S$ its Jacobian matrix at $(x,0)$ is nonsingular since $\nu$ is normal to $S$.

[image: Proposition]

My attempt to deduce this:

$$F(x,t):\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\to V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$$
where
$$
F(x,t)= \left(x_1+\frac{t}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1}(x),\ldots,x_n+\frac{t}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_n}(x)\right)
$$
The Jacobian matrix is
$$
J_f(x,t)\begin{pmatrix}
1+\frac{t}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_1^2}(x) & \cdots & 1+\frac{t}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_1\partial x_n}(x) & \frac{1}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1}(x) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1+\frac{t}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_1\partial x_n}(x) & \cdots & 1+\frac{t}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_n^2}(x) & \frac{1}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_n}(x)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and therefore
$$
J_f(x,0)\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 0 & \frac{1}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1}(x) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 1& \frac{1}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_n}(x)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: No, the domain of $F$ is not $\Bbb R^n\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. To apply the inverse function theorem, you need equal dimensions for domain and range. I would recommend avoiding the derivative matrix entirely, so that you will not need a parametrization for $V$.

Comment: Remember that you only need the derivative when $t=0$. What is the image of the map $dF(x,0)$?

Comment: Since $t=0$, $dF(x,0)=I$ with $I$ the identity matrix on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Certainly not $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$. The key issue is that $T_xS\oplus \nu(x) = \Bbb R^n$.